# PHP Socket Read/Socket Receive

Tags: php, sockets

What's the difference between *socket_read* and *socket_recv*? I'm trying to use PHP sockets but I get this warning using *socket_read*:

```
socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10057]
```

This is the line of coding for that:

```
$strData = socket_read($resSock, 65536, PHP_BINARY_READ);
```

Now when I use *socket_recv*, I get this warning:

```
socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [0]
```

And this is the line:

```
socket_recv($resSock, $strData, 65536, 0);
```

Please help me out here!

Comment: Since both functions are getting the same error, why does the difference between them matter?

Comment: I asked whats the difference Barmar.

Comment: And I answered below. But how is the difference relevant to fixing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`socket_recv` allows you to supply extra flags. `socket_read()` is equivalent to calling `socket_recv()` with `flags = 0`. `socket_read()` also allows you to specify `PHP_NORMAL_READ`, which only reads up to the next newline (so it's then equivalent to `fgets()`).

They're also called slightly differently. `socket_read()` returns the data; `socket_recv()` takes a variable as a reference parameter and updates it, returning the number of bytes read.

Comment: Thanks mate, is there anyway I can get rid of that warning?

Comment: My guess is that `$resSock` is not a valid socket. Post your code that opens the network connection.